# Visual Studio Azure Solution with multiple projects

Tags: git, azure, visual-studio, version-control, team-explorer

My solution contains a main project and a helper Library project that contains utilities that im using within the first project.
I pushed the entire solution onto azure and it did so without issues. However, when i try to pull the solution onto another computer, the main project is loaded but the Library is unloaded, when i try to reload it, it gives me this error: The operation could not be completed.
Upon further looking, i found this error being logged:

C:\Users\user\Source\Repos\Library\Library.csproj : error  : The project file could not be loaded. Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\user\Source\Repos\Library\Library.csproj'.  C:\Users\user\Source\Repos\Library\Library.csproj

Is there a specific way to push and pull solutions with multiple projects? What might be the reason why the second project isnt being loaded ?

Tried to reload the project, but cant seem to resolve the issue.

Comment: How are you managing the references between the projects in your solution?  It looks like you are “adding reference” and then browsing to the location rather than “adding project reference”.

Comment: I added the reference to the library, but still when pushing the library is not being committed, even more, changes done in the Library are not being picked up, so i cannot commit them since they are not showing up as changes in team explorer.

Comment: What are the correct steps to push a solution that contains multiple projects and libraries ?

Comment: What source control are you using?